# C++ messaging using templates

Tags: c++, beginner, template, template-meta-programming

I wanted to allow components of my program to communicate without the components knowing about each other, thus keeping coupling low. So I devised some template classes that implement the observer pattern and allow classes to send messages of any type, providing they inherit from a message interface base class, and a message listener base class, paramaterized by the same message type (please feel free to correct my terminology here!)

Please ignore references to the `LOG` macro; it's just something I use to debug.

```
#ifndef MESSAGING_HPP
#define MESSAGING_HPP
#define LOG(...)

#include <vector>

namespace messaging{

template<typename T>
class IMessageListener;

template <typename T>
class IMessageContext {
    friend class IMessageListener<T>;

    template <typename U>
    friend void send(IMessageContext<U>* ptrContext, const U& _msg);

    template <typename U>
    friend void attach(IMessageContext<U>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<U>* ptrListener);

    template <typename U>
    friend void detach(IMessageContext<U>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<U>* ptrListener);

    std::vector<IMessageListener<T>* > listeners;

    void attachListener( IMessageListener<T>* _listener);
    void detachListener( IMessageListener<T>* _listener);
    void dispatch(const T& _msg);
public:
    ~IMessageContext();
};

template <typename T>
void IMessageContext<T>::attachListener( IMessageListener<T>* _listener)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    listeners.push_back(_listener);
}

template <typename T>
void IMessageContext<T>::detachListener( IMessageListener<T>* _listener)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    listeners.erase(std::remove(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), _listener), listeners.end());
}

template <typename T>
void IMessageContext<T>::dispatch(const T& _msg)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    typename std::vector<IMessageListener<T>* >::iterator i;
    for(i = listeners.begin(); i != listeners.end(); ++i){
        (*i)->handleMessage(_msg);
    }
}

template <typename T>
IMessageContext<T>::~IMessageContext()
{
    //detach from all listeners so they dont try to detach from this context when they are destructed
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    typename std::vector<IMessageListener<T>* >::iterator i;
    for(i = listeners.begin(); i != listeners.end(); ++i){
        (*i)->messaging::template IMessageListener<T>::detachContext(this);
    }
}

template<typename T>
class IMessageListener {
    friend class IMessageContext<T>;

    template <typename U>
    friend void attach(IMessageContext<U>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<U>* ptrListener);

    template <typename U>
    friend void detach(IMessageContext<U>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<U>* ptrListener);

    std::vector<IMessageContext<T>* > contexts;

    void attachContext( IMessageContext<T>* _listener);
    void detachContext( IMessageContext<T>* _listener);
    virtual void handleMessage(const T&)  = 0;
public:
    virtual ~IMessageListener();

};

template <typename T>
void IMessageListener<T>::attachContext( IMessageContext<T>* _context)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    contexts.push_back(_context);
}

template <typename T>
void IMessageListener<T>::detachContext( IMessageContext<T>* _context)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    contexts.erase(std::remove(contexts.begin(), contexts.end(), _context), contexts.end());
}

template <typename T>
IMessageListener<T>::~IMessageListener()
{
    //detach from all contexts so they dont try to message missing listener
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    typename std::vector<IMessageContext<T>* >::iterator i;
    for(i = contexts.begin(); i != contexts.end(); ++i){
        (*i)->messaging::template IMessageContext<T>::detachListener(this);
    }
}

// The real API

template <typename T>
void send(IMessageContext<T>* ptrContext, const T& _msg)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    ptrContext->template IMessageContext<T>::dispatch(_msg);
}

template <typename T>
void attach(IMessageContext<T>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<T>* ptrListener)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    ptrContext->template IMessageContext<T>::attachListener(ptrListener);
    ptrListener->template IMessageListener<T>::attachContext(ptrContext);
}

template <typename T>
void detach(IMessageContext<T>* ptrContext, IMessageListener<T>* ptrListener)
{
    LOG(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    ptrContext->template IMessageContext<T>::detachListener(ptrListener);
    ptrListener->template IMessageListener<T>::detachContext(ptrContext);
}

} //namespace messaging

#endif // MESSAGING_HPP
```

And an example of usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "messaging.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class context : public messaging::IMessageContext<int>,
        public messaging::IMessageContext<std::string>
{
public:
    void go(const int &i)
    {
        messaging::send<int>(this, i);
    }
    void go(const string &s)
    {
        messaging::send<std::string>(this, s);
    }
};

class listener : public messaging::IMessageListener<int>,
        public messaging::IMessageListener<string>
{
    virtual void handleMessage(const int &i){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void handleMessage(const string &i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

public:
    virtual ~listener(){}
};

int main()
{
    context c;
    listener l;

    messaging::attach<int>(&c,&l);
    messaging::attach<std::string>(&c,&l);

    c.go(1234);
    c.go("this is a string message");

    return 0;
}
```

As I am still new to C++ and programming in general, I was hoping to find critique on method and style, as well as thoughts on usefulness and efficiency of the idea.

Answer (score 4):

The big problem here is that you can very easily end up with dangling pointers due to lifetime issues. A really small example:

```
void trouble()
{
    context c;
    listener li;

    messaging::attach<int>(&c, &l);

    return c;
}
```

Can you spot the problem above? We've declared both `context` and `listener` on the stack. When you go to use the returned context with something like `c.go(1234)`, you'll invoke undefined behavior.

The general way of solving this would be to allocate both the context and the listener as `shared_ptr`s. This also involves some trickyness due to the fact that `shared_ptr` is reference counted, and listeners should not keep the reference alive (which they will), thus necessitating the use of `weak_ptr`.

Edit: A bit more detail. In this case, since an `IMessageContext` actually stores a `vector` of `IMessageListener<T>`, it should own the pointers that are passed to it. This suggests you should be using `std::unique_ptr<T>`:

```
using owned_ptr = std::unique_ptr<IMessageListener<T>>;
std::vector<owend_ptr> listeners;

void attachListener( owned_ptr&& listener_);
void detachListener( owned_ptr&& listener-);
void dispatch(const T& _msg);
```

Your `attachListener` implementation would be similar, but would move the pointer in instead of pushing it back:

```
template <typename T>
void IMessageContext<T>::attachListener(owned_ptr&& listener)
{
    listeners.push_back(std::move(listener));
}
```

The benefit of this is that the memory occupied by the vector of listeners is automatically reclaimed when its parent object (in this case, an `IMessageContext` instance) has its destructor called.

This isn't a complete demonstration by any means, but I'd highly recommend you read up about memory ownership and smart pointers in C++, mainly `std::unique_ptr` and `std::smart_ptr`.

---

On a (really) advanced note, you can also do some cool (but tricky!) things with your `context` and `listener` classes. At the moment, these need to be explicitly derived from `IListener<T>` for each specific `T`. Using some magic, you could write this as follows:

```
template <typename Base, typename... Bases>
class context:
    public messaging::IMessaging<Base>,
    public messaging::IMessaging<Bases>...
{
public:
    using messaging::IMessaging<Base>::send;
    using context<Bases...>::send;

    template <typename T>
    void go(const T& t)
    {
        send<T>(this, t);
    }
};

template <typename Base>
class context
  : public messaging::IMessaging<Base>
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void go(const T& t)
    {
        send<T>(this, t);
    }
};
```

And similarly for `listener`. This crazy bit of hackery would allow you to declare your `context` class to receive whatever argument types it wants:

```
context<std::string, int> c;
listener<std::string, int> li;
```

This will effectively derive the context from each `IMeessaging<T>` for each `T` in the list of template arguments supplied to `context/listener`, and then forward to the correct `send` function.

Comment: Could the dangling pointer issue be resolved by having a copy constructor which updates the pointer in all the attached contexts/listeners? The second part of what you said is very cool, going to have to spend some time to understand whats going on though.. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @Rag See my update; I've gone int a little bit more detail on this. Memory management in C++ with complex structures like this can take some getting used to, and I'd highly recommend you do a bit of reading about so called "smart pointers" to understand the problems they solve.